# How to get target methodinfo from a delegate

Tags: c#, reflection

There is a `express x=> x.delegate += null`, 
how to get target `methodinfo` from this express. I know by `il` file , but it's not so friendly,

anyone has any reasonable solution?

```
EventInfo GetTargetMethodInfo(Delegate d)
{
    EventInfo info = null;
    var ilBytes = d.Method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
    var callIdx = Array.IndexOf(ilBytes, (Byte)OpCodes.Ldnull.Value);
    var calledMethodEntry = Array.FindIndex(ilBytes, x => x == OpCodes.Callvirt.Value || x == OpCodes.Call.Value);
    if (callIdx > 0 && callIdx < ilBytes.Length
        && calledMethodEntry > callIdx)
    {
        var pos = calledMethodEntry + 1;
        var methodCode = (((ilBytes[pos++] | (ilBytes[pos++] << 8)) | (ilBytes[pos++] << 0x10)) | (ilBytes[pos++] << 0x18));

        var mi = d.Method.Module.ResolveMethod(methodCode);
        if (mi != null && mi.Name.StartsWith("add_"))
        {
            var evtName = mi.Name.Substring(4);
            info = mi.DeclaringType.GetEvent(evtName);
        }
    }
    return info;
}
```

Comment: something just like moq did

Comment: what `MethodInfo` are you looking to get? if you use an anonymous method (which is what `express x => x.delegate += null` looks kinda like, if it compiled), then the method-info *is the anonymous method*, which probably isn't what you want. So: what method **exactly** are you looking to get here? Heck, if you could show the calling context here, it would make the question a lot easier to grok.

Comment: Note also: searching an array of IL for a particular opcode *using `FindIndex`* is dangerous - it presumes that the thing you're looking for won't ever happen to be an *operand* of another opcode, by coincidence. To do this *properly*, you'd need to walk each opcode, checking how many operands (and their sizes) to discard each time - basically you'd need a full IL parser.

Comment: can I probe at what you're actually trying to do here? it looks like you're trying to describe an arbitrary event accessor, `Bar`, on a type i.e. `class Foo { public event SomeEventType Bar; }`, with the expression `x => x.Bar += null;` as a hack to describe `.Bar`. Frankly... your hack hasn't gained you much - a `string` parameter passed as `nameof(Foo.Bar)` would be *better* (just use `typeof(Foo).GetEvent(eventName)`)

Answer (score 0):

i pretty sure when reached GetTargetMethodInfo the delegate must be like x => x.delegate += null, i know from il it's danger and not so stable once from different compiler. so i want to improve it. eg:

```
public class Proxy : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
public static class Extentsions
{
    public static EventInfo GetTargetEventInfo1<T>(this T source, Action<T> action) 
    {
        return GetTargetEventInfo(action);
    }

    static EventInfo GetTargetEventInfo(Delegate d)
    {
        '''''''
    }   
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        var proxy = new Proxy();
        var eventInfo = proxy.GetEventInfo(x => x.PropertyChanged += null);
    }
}
```

here il would be like

```
0000 : ldarg.1
0001 : ldnull
0002 : callvirt instance System.Void ConsoleApp1.Proxy::add_PropertyChanged()
0007 : nop
0008 : ret
```

the result i want is

```
{System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged}
    AddMethod: {Void add_PropertyChanged(System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler)}
    Attributes: None
    CustomAttributes: Count = 0
    DeclaringType: {Name = "Proxy" FullName = "ConsoleApp1.Proxy"}
    EventHandlerType: {Name = "PropertyChangedEventHandler" FullName = "System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler"}
    IsMulticast: true
    IsSpecialName: false
    MemberType: Event
    MetadataToken: 335544321
    Module: {ConsoleApp1.exe}
    Name: "PropertyChanged"
    RaiseMethod: null
    ReflectedType: {Name = "Proxy" FullName = "ConsoleApp1.Proxy"}
    RemoveMethod: {Void remove_PropertyChanged(System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler)}
```

same thing from moq you will see

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo> { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock };
mock.Raise(x => x.Event += null, EventArgs.Empty);
public interface IFoo
{               
    event EventHandler Event;
}
```

if you step inside moq, you will found code, moq using CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget from Castle.Core

```
var expression = ExpressionReconstructor.Instance.ReconstructExpression(action, mock.ConstructorArguments);
var parts = expression.Split();
```

here stored in parts is what i want. but need some more readable solution for developer.